# Event occurs after clicking a Flash (.swf file type)

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

This code will open a Flash in a Window after being executed. Is there any way to do: When clicking the  Flash (without adding any button), any event will occur?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\IBM\Desktop\snailrunner1.swf";
        SWFFileHeader swfFile = new SWFFileHeader(filePath);
        this.Width = swfFile.FrameSize.WidthInPixels;
        this.Height = swfFile.FrameSize.HeightInPixels;

        WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        FormFlashLibrary.FlashAxControl play = new FormFlashLibrary.FlashAxControl();

        host.Child = play;

        grdMain.Children.Add(host);

        play.Width = (int) this.Width;
        play.Height = (int) this.Height;

        play.LoadMovie(filePath);
        play.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Explain me why do you add a button?

Comment: l'm not adding any button. My aim is to: Click the flash and occur an event without any button at all.

Comment: I can't understand your problem, where you put your flash?

Comment: @Likurg: There is not a problem at all, all going smooth, jz that this is kind of new research: Clicking a Flash which appear in a Window, and occur an event. Do u have any idea how to do that? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to achieve.

If you just want to handle click event of the WindowsFormHost, which could be considered as a container, there are several events exposed: [WindowsFormsHost Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx)

If you want to respond to a specific flash control inside the flash content it's required that it's exposed by the flash itself. [Using the external API with an ActiveX container](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb0.html)